# Are there typically any provisions in systems or succession that nullify a successor’s claim to the position if they off their predecessor themselves?

Tags: united-kingdom, any-jurisdiction, murder, succession, monarchy

Suppose Prince William killed King Charles, would he still become king? Was this historically the case in the UK or other monarchies? Or if Kamala kills Joe?

Comment: "Treason doth never prosper: what's the reason? Why, if it prosper, none dare call it treason."

Comment: @alexg love that. what’s the source?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Harington_(writer) - Elizabethan courtier and inventor of the toilet flush